How is classical deamination and enzymatic deamination performed (vanillylamine to vanillin)?
I would like to ask 2 questions, one technical and one about bibliographic recommendations.
Technical question:
I am studying chemistry, the subject bio-organic chemistry.
Browsing the internet I have discovered that capsaicin has a structural component of vanillin.
First I was wondering if there is any “easy” way to obtain vanillin from vanillamine by classical synthetic procedures.
I think a deamination would be necessary, but I don't know of any direct reaction for this purpose. I have thought perhaps of an oxidation by KMnO4 but it could still affect the other groups of vanillamine .
What would be the best classical procedure to oxidize the amine without affecting the other groups?
Perhaps diazonium salts? But this is a benzylamine not an aniline, so I don't know the effectiveness.

On the other hand I would like to know the possibility of doing it by some enzymatic procedure. Of course, I am currently studying the bioorganic subject, this question is normal. However, would a transaminase, a mono amine oxidase be necessary?
My knowledge of enzymatic biotransformations is very limited and I would like to expand my knowledge in this field. Can you recommend any introductory books to learn about biotransformations?

there's a good chance that there's an NAD-dependent amine dehydrogenase that will do the reaction, but you'll have to look through the literature to find one with the right specificity. Similarly, there are omega-aminotransferases that will take benzylamine, but you'll have to look for one that will accept vanillamine

'Classical' deaminations have always been difficult. For enzymes: you might want to look at bioisosteres. Hydroxyl groups are chemically 'equivalent enough' to amine groups that enzymes generally will work on both. With this in mind, I found at least two papers that suggest the enzyme vanillyl alcohol oxidase will oxidize vanillylamine to vanillin. You can read them here and here.
